# I can't understand this question.

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

the function *f* is defined by *f(x)=m+x/2+3x* for all value of *x* except when *x=h*.Find the value of *h*  .

Comment: (1) Did you mean $$f(x)=\frac{m+x}2+3x\;,\;\;f(x)=m+\frac x2+3x\;,\;\;f(x)=m+\frac x{2+3x}\;,\ldots$$or what?? (2) If nothing more's given (say, the function is continuous everywhere) it is impossible to answer the question

Comment: or...$$f(x) = \frac{m+x}{2+3x}\;?$$ The point is, please use parentheses to parse the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way $f(x)$ may possibly be undefined requires that $2+ 3x$ is intended to be a denominator, as in the cases

$$f(x)=m+\frac x{2+3x}\;\text{ and } \;f(x) = \frac{m+x}{2+3x}$$

Denominators cannot be zero, since division by zero is *undefined*, so in either of the two cases above, $f(x)$ is undefined at any value $x$ at which $2+3x = 0 $.

> When is $2 + 3x = 0$?

The solution to this equation is the $h$ you need.